# How to create a slide to show product when mouse moving to cart icon in woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

How to create a slide to show product when mouse moving to cart icon in woocommerce?
Like screenshot below

[image: hover mouse]

Its my header.php script

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme.
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package themetest
 */

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'gg' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation2" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="top-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Top Menu', 'gg' ); ?></button>

        <?php
global $woocommerce;

// get cart quantity
$qty = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

// get cart total
$total = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();

// get cart url
$cart_url = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url();

// if multiple products in cart
if($qty>1)
      echo '<ul class="menu nav-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="'.$cart_url.'">'.$qty.' <i class="cart_control">::before</i></a></li> </ul>';

// if single product in cart
if($qty==1)
      echo '<a href="'.$cart_url.'">1 product | '.$total.'</a>';

?>


            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'top', 'menu_id' => 'top-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) : ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'gg' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

Its style.css just for top bar navigation

```
  /* top bar. */
.main-navigation2 {
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    background: #fff;

}

.main-navigation2 ul {
    display: none;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

.main-navigation2 li {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}

.main-navigation2 a {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #ff3400 url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right / 20% 20%;
}

.main-navigation2 a:first-child {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 60px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 60px;
    background: #ff3400 url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right / 20% 20%;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;

}

.main-navigation2 a:last-child {
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #ff3400 url(img/arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right / 20% 20%;


}

.main-navigation2 ul ul {
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.5em;
    left: -999em;
    z-index: 99999;
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul ul {
    left: -999em;
    top: 0;
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul a {
    width: 200px;
    line-height: 40px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    display: block;

}

.main-navigation2 ul ul li {

}

.main-navigation2 li:hover > a,
.main-navigation2 li.focus > a {
background: #e6370a;

}

.main-navigation2 ul ul :hover > a,
.main-navigation2 ul ul .focus > a {
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul a:hover,
.main-navigation2 ul ul a.focus {
}

.main-navigation2 ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation2 ul li.focus > ul {
    left: auto;
}

.main-navigation2 ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation2 ul ul li.focus > ul {
    left: 100%;
}

.main-navigation2 .current_page_item > a,
.main-navigation2 .current-menu-item > a,
.main-navigation2 .current_page_ancestor > a {
}

.main-navigation2 .cart_control {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 20px 0 19px;
    width: 30px;
    float: right;
    background: url('img/icons/set_icons/cart-grey.png') center no-repeat;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 9999em;
    overflow: hidden;

}


.main-navigation2 .cart_wrapper {
    text-align: left;
    position:  absolute;
    width: 300px;
    right: -2px;

    background-color: #494949;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    color: #fff;
}
/* Small menu. */
.menu-toggle,
.main-navigation2.toggled ul,
.main-navigation.toggled ul {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    .menu-toggle {
        display: none;
    }
    .main-navigation ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .main-navigation2 ul {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Or you can checkout [this website](https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-added-to-cart-popup/) for further info like I said above.
I am using latest woocommerce plugin.

Comment: Can you please add html instead of PHP script inside that.. So get Idea of your Nav structure.

Comment: @Mitul done. Please recheck again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change over here

First change the code

```
if($qty==1)
      echo '<ul class='mini-cart'><li><a href="'.$cart_url.'">1 product | '.$total.'</a><div class="cart-Items">' woocommerce_mini_cart() '</div> <li></ul>';
```

CSS changes

```
.mini-cart li {
 position:relative;
}
.mini-cart li ul{
 position:absolute;
 display:none;
}
.mini-cart li:hover ul{
 display:block;
}
```

This is not complete design but you will get the minicart and display that cart on hover.

Comment: your code have syntax error and fixed it but give error result like this: http://imgur.com/YjNEiiS